# Nancy with Complex object using JSON not working

Tags: nancy

Client code:

```
 var basket = {
            products: [],
            user: { name: "schugh" }
        };

    $("#basket table tr").each(function (index, item) {
        var product = $(item).data('product');
        if (product) {
            basket.products.push(product);
        }

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:12116/basketrequest/1",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(basket),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert(exception);
        }
    });
```

Server code:

```
 Post["/basketrequest/{id}"] = parameters =>
 {     
     var basketRequest = this.Bind(); //basketrequest is null
     return Response.AsJson(basketRequest , HttpStatusCode.OK);
 };
```

Other model classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class BasketRequest
{
    public User User;
    public List<Product> Products;
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public ProductStatus ProductStatus { get; set; }
}

public enum ProductStatus
{
    Created,
    CheckedBy,
    Published
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The code in the Nancy Module `this.Bind();` returns `null`. If I change the Complex object to just `List<Product>`, i.e. with no wrapper `BasketRequest`, the object is fine...

Any pointers?

**EDIT**: JSON posted:

```
{
  "User": { 
    "Name": "SChugh" 
  },
  "Products": [{ 
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Tomato Soup",
    "Category": "Groceries",
    "Price": 1
  }, { 
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Yo-yo",
    "Category": "Toys",
    "Price": 3.75
  }]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the json, have you tried the generic method `this.Bind<BasketRequest>()`

Comment: {
"User":{ "Name": "SChugh" },
"Products":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Tomato Soup","Category":"Groceries","Price":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Yo-yo","Category":"Toys","Price":3.75}]
}

Comment: @jjchiw I tried with lower case as well and that too didn't work! I am stuck!

Comment: @jjchiw I have tried the Generic method this.Bind<BasketRequest>(); and that too does not work

Comment: Shouldn't your two fields in the basket request object be properties?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `BasketRequest` object should implement properties instead of fields. So

```
public class BasketRequest
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

also you should probably use the generic method too

```
this.Bind<BasketRequest>();
```